# How to store locale in django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to store a locale as a user preference field in a custom User model.

Before I go an hardcode a list of ISO-839-1 locales and set them as choices of a CharField, is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Appreciate you asking this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) is the standard name for "western" character encoding, not a list of locales. You possibly meant the [language codes in ISO-639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes).

If you mean to store localization code as a user's language/dialect, you may use Django's own supported list of common 87 languages; refer to `django.conf.locale`.

This module also includes locale metadata, and a full translation of admin interface. For example, an excerpt from `django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO`:

```
LANG_INFO = {
    # ...
    'vi': {
        'bidi': False,
        'code': 'vi',
        'name': 'Vietnamese',
        'name_local': 'Tiếng Việt',
    },
    # ...
}
```

[Source in Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#localized-names-of-languages)